# Is it possible to tell GCC Linker in Linker script file which memory a section shall use?

Tags: gcc, linker, linker-scripts

I am using a GCC (Version 5.3.0) based development environment. Is it possible to say to the linker that a specific section shall use either memory1 or memory2 dependent on the size of the section?

An example for better understanding:

```
MEMORY
{
  ....
  ....
  SRAM (RWX)        : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 112K
  SRAM2 (RWX)        : ORIGIN = 0x64000000, LENGTH = 2M
}

SECTIONS
{
  ...
  ...

  .bss :
  {
     ... 
     ...
  } > (if size of bss is bigger than SRAM use SRAM2 else SRAM)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of I am using FreeRTOS I found this solution:
[STM32F4 running FreeRTOS in external RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316358/stm32f4-running-freertos-in-external-ram)

I am using heap4.c in this it is possible to move complete heap in a dedicated memory area.
Since heap5.c is available in FreeRTOS, this file can also be used for my quastion.